# Installing PyGST with Cygwin

Tags: python, build, cygwin, compilation, gstreamer

I've given up on the OSSBuild of PyGST (Gstreamer) due to several major bugs. Instead, I am building from source myself.

However, I have hit a snag. I am running this build in Cygwin. After unpacking the tarball, I run ./configure in the unpacked folder. I get the following error after a little while:

> configure: error: you need gstreamer development packages installed:

Where do I download this? I have the latest version of GStreamer compiled and installed (also via Cygwin, without any issues.)

Comment: You get this worked out?

Comment: I've been off this week. Will try it when I return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell it where to look for the headers from that GStreamer build, or copy them to (the cygwin version of) `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/incude`.

Try `./configure --help` to see what option would let you pass the header dir. Also, back in the GStreamer dir, take a look in the makefile -- it may have already installed the headers somewhere, just not where PyGst is looking. You can check in subdirs under (the cygwin version of) `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include` too.